# Android TalkBack keep highlighted position on Screen Rotation

Tags: android, position, restore, screen-rotation, talkback

Use case:

1. Enable the *Google TalkBack* accessibility service and navigate to an
   app (e.g. *Google Messenger*)
2. In this app, assuming that you'll be presented with a **list** of items 
   to select, arbitrarily navigate to one of them using Talkback gestures (*swipe right* or just *click once* on one of them)
3. Rotate the screen

Expected behaviour:

- The previously highlighted item should still be highlighted; the user
  should be able to continue it's navigation
- The Google Messenger app is a perfect example of this correct
  behaviour

[Messenger After rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA9xY.jpg)

My *Sunshine* app behaviour:

- The previously highlighted item is not highlighted after Screen
  Rotation
- The user has to navigate again to the previously selected item
- Depending on the screen, finding and having an item selected again can be a pain... not what we want to induce to our user

[Sunshine After rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83M5b.jpg)

**How should we implement this?**
I'm thinking, as a solution, at Accessibility Events and intercepting them... but this doesn't seem to be right, doesn't seem to be "best practice" (e.g. creating a Custom View and implement the methods handling these Events)

**!** Note that the green highlighted list item doesn't seem to be focused (*getCurrentFocused()* returns **null**)

**!** Note that the list items become focused if we use D-Pad navigation, instead of TalkBack navigation (but this is another discussion...)

---

L.E:

- I've spend a whole day on this, trying to "get the focus" of the
  highlighted item, but the item is NOT *focused*. This is why I assume
  that this feature must be tackled in some other way and I would like
  to know your (**!**) experienced **opinion** before I spend another 2 days
  re-creating all the used Android components (as I assume it could be done - this doesn't sound *very* "best practice", doesn't it **?**)
- This is NOT a *homework*, there's nothing wrong with my current code
  (so, there's no code to post, unless one would like my whole project)
  and, given that this is my first post, I could not attach more than 2
  pictures (this is why the "before" screens are missing)
- Just give me a good hint, based on experience, and I will **implement** it and post the finished, working **code** here.

Comment: Two things: 1st: This looks like a homework... For this (as for any other questions on Stackoverflow) show the effort you have done to solve this! If there is no code and with that no errors you are wrong here! 2nd: If this has something to do with Android (teeny tiny hint here) there is a tag for that. The other tags you have used are most likely not directly visited by others as they might apply to any programming language!

Comment: This is NOT homework!
"Sunshine" is an app developed as a part of a free course (Udacity - "Developing Android apps").
There is no code because my code has nothing wrong! I'm not asking here "why is my code failing? here's a sample!".
I'm asking "how do you do such a thing". The answer is simple if you did this already, in your life.

Please, don't troll my first and only post...

Comment: I know that this is your first post as due to the review queue. This has not been intended to troll around at all. The formulation of the question implies the feeling of a copy&pasted task from somewhere and this, in most cases, are homeworks unfortunately. And if your code has nothing wrong and it works why the question. I have not implemented something like this but I do not really get your point to be honest. Why do you ask if you already have working code?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I'm trying to get this implemented as a sensible Feature. I guess it looks like an assignment, due to the "bullet points" and "use cases", but this is how I thought I could explain the situation I'm in. Google insists that accessibility is top priority and I feel like the described situation is highly important and I found myself unable to implement it.
Just give me a good hint, based on experience, and I will implement it and post the finished, working code here.

Comment: I am way to unexperienced in this topic but I saw your post in the review queue supposed to tell my oppinion on the question. Do not worry as the upvote speaks for itself :) I am sure you will get your answer soon with the appropriate tag set!

Comment: Tank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It should work out of the box if you implement stable IDs in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` (and potentially disable the `ItemAnimator` on the `RecyclerView` (`rv.setItemAnimator(null)`) which you can do conditionally if TalkBack is enabled).

Here's [a blog post I wrote about the item animator bug](https://www.novoda.com/blog/losing-focus/).

Comment: Interesting answer.
When wrote here about this challenge I was using a ListView. Now, I switched to a RecyclerView.
I'll try to implement this accessibility feature again (as I postponed the matter).
I'll let you know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while working on the same project.

Hint: `listView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean value);`

Good luck :)

Comment: I moved on, but your suggestion makes me curious! Thank you very much!